# Run and print reports at android

Tags: android, printing, crystal-reports, report, reporting

I create an application and I want to run and print reports (like crystal reports to at .net). What is the easiest way to do that? To be more specific I create an application that user will create invoices at his customers and print them at a bluetooth printer. Is there any easy way like crystal reports for android? I tried to use crystal reports for eclipse but the libraries does not work on android (at least I do not know how to).

Answer (score 3):

First off, Android has no built-in or native printing capabilities simply because Android has no concept of what printers are.

However, you can use third party libraries.

To answer your question properly, you will have to specify which versions of Android you plan to support with your application. Because some of the various third party libraries only support certain versions of Android.

In addition to including a third party printing library in your application, you can send out a broadcast intent with the data you would like printed, and depending on what applications are installed on the users' device, the user could select an app that supports printing the type of data you send in the intent.

You could also use Google's new Cloud Printing service. This would be my preferable choice, but to actually print to a physical printer the user will need a desktop pc, server, or Mac that either has a printer connected to it or has a network capable printer installed and configured. At this point, this is probably your best bet.

This is really a difficult issue to tackle for a few reasons. First, you will need to figure out what you're going to print, you will need to format it in a way that can be printed (PDF, PostScript, or ASCII would name a few). Next you will have to figure out if you're going to support printing to printers that are not Bluetooth capable, so if you plan to support printing to a network capable printer, you will have to be on the same LAN/VLAN as the WLAN that the Android device is connected to and AP isolation will need to be disabled. If you plan to support shared Windows printer, Mac OS X Bonjour printer shares, or Zeroconf Linux printer shares then you will need to either find supporting libraries and implement a way to search for the various network shares and then a way to select and store which network share to print to.

Since you plan to support printing to Bluetooth capable printers; then there are a few Ice Cream Sandwich and Honeycomb distributions which are capable of pairing with Bluetooth printers (the Android versions would need to be 3.0 or 3.1+ [I am not completely  sure at what SDK level for Honeycomb that Bluetooth printing protocols were implemented] and 4.0.3+). As for actually formatting the data to be printed over Bluetooth, I am unsure what can be printed and what Bluetooth versions or protocols are used. I will do some further research this morning and I will post back with the information I can come up with.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I started developing for 2.1 but I have no problem to go to 4.0.3+ if I have to. I do not to use cloud because users will work offline. Their devices will not be connected to internet. They will be drivers who visit customers. I want to print invoice from sqlite. That is why I search a solution like crystal reports.

Comment: Nice detailed answer JBDynamics. Excuse my ignorance here but assuming you call a 'Print' function in 3rd party components wouldn't the format it uses be predetermined? I guess my mistake is assuming these libraries would even implement a way to print to Android at all right? Meaning, if they don't do it natively you'd have to massage your data into PDF/PostScript/ASCII/etc. THEN send it to the cloud or wherever you plan on printing?